# famo.us - how to get a callback when a paginated scrollview goes to a new page?

Tags: javascript, pagination, famo.us

I'm using a paginated famous scrollview, and want to load some extra content when the user swipes to a new page. I can't see any callbacks or way to set this up.

I would expect to be able to do something like

`myview.onChange = function(page) { // handle change }`

additionally there's no way to query the current page that a scrollView is displaying?

info appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply listen for the 'pageChange' event (with paginated:true.)

```
scrollView.on('pageChange', function() {
        alert('change');
    });
```

Comment: actually this doesn't seem to work for scrolling backwards, but otherwise yep. bug is documented.